# ¿Cómo puedo pasar el detalle de un registro a una ventana Modal con Ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, mvc

Quiero mostrar el detalle de cada registro por el `ID` mostrándolo en un *popout*, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo? Ya que de esta forma no me esta reconociendo el JavaScript y me da este error:

> Server Error in '/' Application. The following sections have been
>   defined but have not been rendered for the layout page
>   "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml": "script".

```
<script>
    function LlamadaParcial() {
       var UrlDeLaVista = '@Url.Action("Details", "VisitaNegocios")';
        $.Ajax({
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: UrlDeLaVista,
            data: {},
            success: function (response) {
                $("#resultado").html('');
                $("#resultado").html(response);

            }
        });
    }
```

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="resultado">

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: La función `LlamadaParcial()` cómo la mandas llamar?

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="btnDetails" onclick="LlamadaParcial()"><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-2x"></i></button>

Comment: de esa forma en una tabla

Comment: tu vista `@Url.Action("Details", "VisitaNegocios")` necesita de un `_layoutPage`?

Comment: no, esta referenciado de la siguiente forma ...  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas teniendo un problema con la view que defines, habria que analizar el `.cshtml` y ver si le asignas un `Layout.cshtml`, por lo visto en el mensaje si lo haces

Pero este layout esta definiendo un section que no respectas en la view

[Layout View](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/layout-view-in-asp.net-mvc)

Si en el layout visualizas la definicion de algo como ser

```
@RenderSection("script")
```

es porque en la view que definas debes tener

```
@section script {

    //aqui codigo

}
```

si queres hacer esto opcional debes cambiarlo en el _Layout.cshtml indicando

```
@RenderSection("script", required: false)
```